# Let the functions $f$ and $g$ be differentiable on $(a,b)$ show that $f(x)^2-g(x)^2=1$

Tags: calculus, limits

such that $f'(x)=g(x),g'(x)=f(x)$   $ \forall  x\in (a,b)$

Further more $f(x_0)=1$ and $g(x_0)=0$ for some $x_0\in (a,b)$

Show that

> $f(x)^2-g(x)^2=1$

by defination

$f'(x_0)=g(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{f(x)-1}{x-x_0}=0$

similarly

$g'(x_0)=f(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{g(x)-g(x_0)}{x-x_0}=\lim_{x\to x_0}\dfrac{g(x)-0}{x-x_0}=1$

How can we deduce the identity above having solved these limits

Comment: I think you should try to calculate the derivative of $x \mapsto (f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2$.

Comment: same as derivative of $(f(x)-g(x))(f(x)+g(x))$ ?

Comment: This is the dericative at $x\to$ 
$2f(x)f'(x)-2g(x)g'(x)$

Comment: And now use the assumptions on $f'$ and $g'$!

Comment: it gives $0$ if i let $x=x_0$

Comment: meaning $f^2-g^2=c$

Comment: And now you can determine the constant by looking at the value for $x = x_0$.

Comment: very helpful,great hint

Comment: Jonas, it gives $0$ for all $x \in (a, b)$.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have in general

$((f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2)' = 2f'(x)f(x) - 2g'(x)g(x); \tag{1}$

using the given hypothesis

$f'(x) = g(x) \tag{2}$

and

$g'(x) = f(x), \tag{3}$

we see that

$2f'(x)f(x) - 2g'(x)g(x) = 2(f'(x)f(x) - g'(x)g(x))$
$= 2(g(x)f(x) - f(x)g(x)) = 0; \tag{4}$

combining (1) and (4) we find

$((f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2)' = 0, \tag{5}$

which shows that $(f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2$ is constant on $(a, b)$

and now using the further hypothesis that

$f(x_0) = 1, \;\; g(x_0) = 0 \tag{6}$

we find

$((f(x_0))^2 - (g(x_0))^2) = (1^2 - 0^2) = 1, \tag{7}$

so, since it is constant,

$((f(x))^2 - (g(x))^2) = 1, \tag{8}$

everywhere on $(a, b)$.  ***QED.***

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: soo clean,more than helpful...et facta est lux

Comment: Thanks so much for the kind words!  I think your Latin is more advanced than mine, however *felix dies Nativitatis!!!*  Cheers!

Comment: Thanks to Google :). Laetum diem habe  festum!

Comment: Yeah, google is great for Latin and Greek, etc!  *gaudete omnes, nunc est bibendum!*